# Generating XML stream in Android

Tags: android, xml, sax, stax

I have to send a large xml document from an android client to a server as a stream. I cannot use DOM parser due to memory constraints. I require something like a SAX parser, but SAX can only parse the data. Is there any library for this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I generate the xml data on the fly. I do not read from a file.

Comment: If you have to send a document -a file- you don't have to parse it. Just send it like any other file in an outputstream.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I generate the xml data on the fly. I do not read from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just hand generate the XML. It is not too hard and certainly no harder than using a SAX parser to parse the XML.

Comment: Yes, that is an option for me. I wanted to know if there is a standard library to do this.

Comment: Well any general purpose library will have to have a full in-memory representation of the XML in order to generate the XML - namely a DOM tree - leading back to a DOM parser-generator.